# SQL Azure Federations pricing

Tags: azure-sql-database

If I have a single 1gb database it costs $10 per month. If I set up federations, so for example I have 5 federations, is it still $10 per month or does each federation cost $10 ($50 total) ?

If it is the former that is better as I can just have a single federation per tenant (client) and increase the database size as more clients sign up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Federations, you can scale your application out across multiple federation members. Each federation member is a SQL Azure database and can be controlled as you can do with your databases today in terms of max size and SKU (web/business). You can choose to scale out to lots of small 1 GB databases, or fewer 10 GB databases for example.

In SQL Azure, you get billed on the collection of all databases you use in the system prorated to a day. In the case of federations, the same logic apply; the cost of the federation is the collection of its federation members (+ the root database which can be any normal database).

Comment: So that would be $50 for 1 x 1gb database with 4 federations?

Comment: Yes, that would give you one root DB + 4 federation members = 5 databases.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/f08f643d-8097-4a4c-adf9-3710efb1bd61/) it is confirmed by an answer from Microsoft representative.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal pricing on Federations just yet; however since you are essentially creating new databases, it would seem appropriate to expect to pay for each federated member.

Answer (score -1):

The answers here so far have been conjecture.

One of the main points of having the federation is that you only get charged for the actual databases being used.  From my understanding, in a SaaS implementation for example with 100 federations in a single database there should ony be the charge for one database.  This allows for scaling out cost effectively.

Comment: Ideally that would be the case, but from all I can gather federations will be priced as if they are separate databases. Much more expensive.

Comment: fortunately that is not the case.  not charged as separate databases - if it was - what would be the point?

Comment: Hi Drewid, can you point me to references. From what I have seen federations are priced as separate databases.